# emoji on web with javascript

Tags: javascript, emoji

Im doing a chat and i would like to add emoji support.

```
var emoji = " :a :b :c :( :d :O :e :f :D :g :L :l :m :^ :* :v :) :# :p := :o :; :r :x :1 :2 :3";
var emoticons = {
':a'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/angel.png" title="angel" alt=":a" class="embtn"/>',
':b'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/apple.png" title="apple" alt=":b" class="embtn"/>',
':c'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/confused.png" title="confused" alt=":c" class="embtn"/>',
':('  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/cry.png" title="cry" alt=":(" class="embtn"/>',
':d'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/devil.png" title="devil" alt=":d" class="embtn" />',
':O'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/gasp.png" title="gasp" alt=":O" class="embtn"/>',
':e'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/frown.png" title="frown" alt=":e" class="embtn"/>',
':f'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/glasses.png" title="glasses" alt=":f" class="embtn"/>',
':D'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/grin.png" title="grin" alt=":D" class="embtn"/>',
':g'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/grumpy.png" title="grumpy" alt=":g" class="embtn"/>',
':L'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/heart-beat.png" title="hearts" alt=":L" class="embtn"/>',
':l'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/heart.png" title="heart" alt=":l" class="embtn"/>',
':m'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/broken-heart.png" title="broken-heart" alt=":m" class="embtn"/>',
':^'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/kiki.png" title="kiki" alt=":^" class="embtn"/>',
':*'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/kiss.png" title="kiss" alt=":*" class="embtn"/>',
':v'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/pacman.png" title="pacman" alt=":v" class="embtn"/>',
':)'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/smile.png" title="smile" alt=":)" class="embtn"/>',
':#'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/squint.png" title="squint" alt=":#" class="embtn"/>',
':p'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/tongue.png" title="tongue" alt=":p" class="embtn"/>',
':='  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/unsure.png" title="unsure" alt=":=" class="embtn"/>',
':o'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/upset.png" title="upset" alt=":o" class="embtn"/>',
':;'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/wink.png" title="Wink" alt=":;" class="embtn"/>',
':r'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/rose.png" title="Rose" alt=":r" class="embtn"/>',
':x'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/poo.png" title="Poo" alt=":x" class="embtn"/>',
':1'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/ears.png" title="Poo" alt=":1" class="embtn"/>',
':2'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/mouth.png" title="Poo" alt=":2" class="embtn"/>',
':3'  :  '<img src="emotions-fb/eyes.png" title="Poo" alt=":3" class="embtn"/>',
}

function Emotions (text) {

    if (text == null || text == undefined || text == "") return;
        var pattern = /:-?[()*^#=;abcdDefghilLmoOprvxz123]/gi;
        return text.replace(pattern, function (match) {
            return typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ? emoticons[match] : match;
        });
    }
}
```

this is my code the emoji change when is send the message but it only works when i send something like :) or :p it doesnt help with bigger ones like :poop: i cant rlly understand why... and when i refresh or the other person receives the message it stays like it was original only the characters not the image...

Comment: what's there in emoticons array.. images ? ok it's characters so it depends on the browser how it interprets it. Alternatively you can define your own emoji and render it with <img> tag once you have those images in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your regex pattern - it matches for ":" followed by optional "-" and then one character from a set "[()*^#=;abcdDefghilLmoOprvxz123]"

So it cannot match ":poop:" - check it with some interactive regex tester like for instance: https://regex101.com/r/dkZVpA/1

To match for:

```
:)
:-)
:poop
:poop:
```

you can use a pattern:

```
/:-?[()*^#=;abcdDefghilLmoOprvxz123]+:?/gi
```

Just have fun with the regex tester! :)

As for the images you'd have to show us some more code - where are they and how are you trying to retrieve them.

Comment: nice it worked that part! thx!!! for the images yeah i think im not doing this quite right i tought that the script would change the pattern but i was wrong.. so i have to make a script that is always looking for the characters and replacing them with this function right? is this the best way to do it?

Comment: my ideia was that every time that a var emoji was there on the chat it would be replaced by the var emoticon xD i dont have a clue how to do this i just started with javascript 1 month ago :s

Comment: it is hard to say what is happening in the rest of your code but the function Emotions(text) does now what is should - for Emotions(':)') it returns: '<img src="emotions-fb/smile.png" title="smile" alt=":)" class="embtn"/>'

Comment: the code that is replacing is this...

$(document).ready(function(){
    originalTitle = document.title;
    startChatSession();

    $([window, document]).blur(function(){
        windowFocus = false;
    }).focus(function(){
        windowFocus = true;
        document.title = originalTitle;
    });

    emoji = Emotions (emoji);
    var emojiDiv = '<div class="emoji-panel-body target-emoji" style="display: none;"><div class="emoji-Recent">'+emoji+'</div></div>';

    $("#right").append(emojiDiv);
    scrollDown();
});

how can i make it to replace in all the <body>?